# Trying to extract MRTG info from a webpage using curl and sed

Tags: html, curl, sed, extract

I am trying to extract some info from an MRTG page to track, namely the 5-minute Max, Avg and Cur values under class 'in" for the 5 minute graph.

So far, I have come up with

```sh
curl -s http://xxx.com/1.2.3.4.html | sed -n '/Begin `Daily/,/End `Daily/p' | sed -n '/>In/\<\/tr/p'
```

which gets me this

```
                                       <th scope="row">In</th>
                                    <td>2291.2 kb/s (2.3%)</td>
                                    <td>439.3 kb/s (0.4%) </td>
                                    <td>141.3 kb/s (0.1%) </td>
                            </tr>
```

Now, I need to extract the 3 numeric kb/s values in class "in", separated by spaces if possible.

How would I do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
... | grep -Po '[\d.]+(?= kb)' | perl -l40pe0
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that I might need to just get the 3rd and last value instead of all 3. I am trying to figure out the answer on how to make the change. Any hint would be really appreciated! Thanks again!

Comment: tail -1 after grep would do

Comment: It worked. I didn't think of head/tail, I was trying to find a way to alter grep but couldn't find anything. Thank you!